# How to augment scons' $*COMSTR

Tags: scons

I can define a custom build command output by [defining $*COMSTR in my environment](http://scons.org/doc/1.2.0/HTML/scons-user/x1884.html):

```
env['CXXCOMSTR'] = compile_source_message
```

However, this overrides the message shown for the build command. I want to augment the message instead, e.g. by prefixing it with the target. My goal is to have a message like this:

```
% scons
Compiling foo.o
cc -o foo.o -c foo.c
```

I tried the following:

```
env['CXXCOMSTR'] = compile_source_message + '\n' + env['CXXCOMSTR']
```

However, this doesn't work because `CXXCOMSTR` is not in `env` yet, I get a `KeyError: 'CXXCOMSTR'`.

How can I augment/prefix the default `$*COMSTR`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're having is due to the following behavior:

If the *COMSTR evaulates to a null string, then the CommandAction object which undelies the Action for this will default to using the *COM string to generate the output.

```
try:
    print env.Dump('CXXCOMSTR')
except KeyError as e:
    print env.Dump('CXXCOM')
```

Would output the value you're looking for. And for your specific usage:

```
try:
    env['CXXCOMSTR'] = compile_source_message + '\n' + env['CXXCOMSTR']
except: KeyError as e:
    env['CXXCOMSTR'] = compile_source_message + '\n' + env['CXXCOM']
```

Of course if some logic in your build were to later on alter the value of CXXCOM then that change would not affect your new setting.

If you wanted to ensure that changes to CXXCOM would propogate to your new value of CXXCOMSTR then the following should work:

```
if env.get('CXXCOMSTR',False):
    env['CXXCOMSTR'] = compile_source_message + '\n' + env['CXXCOMSTR']
else:
    env['CXXCOMSTR'] = "%s \n $CXXCOM"%compile_source_message
```

Note that having the $CXXCOM(*) in your new CXXCOMSTR allows SCons to substitute and fully expand the output for each target.

Comment: Are you sure that the last code snippet in your examples works? Looks like you're defining CXXCOMSTR by referencing itself...at least in the "true" branch.

Comment: Thanks, that's a simple solution. Even easier: `env['CXXCOMSTR'] = compile_source_message + '\n' + env.get('CXXCOMSTR', env['CXXCOM'])`

Comment: morxa - Definitely a better solution!

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, there is currently no environment variable like "`$ACTIONCMD`" containing the full command string for the running build step. So what you're trying to do:

```
env['CXXCOMSTR'] = "Compiling $TARGET:\n$ACTIONCMD"
```

isn't possible. It would require changing the SCons core sources, so it's not impossible in the long run. ;)

However, when creating a new `Action` object you can also specify a `callable` instead of a simple command string via the `strfunction` argument. Within this function you could then compile the printed string to your liking. Search the [MAN page](http://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-man.html) for the keyword `strfunction` to get an impression, and then decide for yourself whether you want to take this route or not. Please also consider subscribing to our user [mailing list](http://scons.org/lists.html) `scons-users@scons.org` for questions like this.