# COMSTR based on COM

Tags: scons

How can a COMSTR be made from a COM to include the full command being executed. For example:

```
env = Environment(CPPPATH='/opt/foo:/opt/bar')
print(env['CXXCOM'])
env['CXXCOMSTR'] = 'fizz\n$CXXCOM\nbuzz'
env.Object('a.cpp')
```

prints

```
$CXX -o $TARGET -c $CXXFLAGS $CCFLAGS $_CCCOMCOM $SOURCES
fizz
g++ -o a.o -c     $( -I/opt/foo -I/opt/bar $) a.cpp
buzz
```

When `g++ -o a.o -c -I/opt/foo -I/opt/bar a.cpp` is expected on line 3. What is the simplest way to get the expected output?

[How to augment scons' $*COMSTR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35329543/how-to-augment-scons-comstr) has an accepted answer along the lines of `env['CXXCOMSTR'] = 'fizz\n$CXXCOM\nbuzz'` which does not work, and another answer saying there is nothing built into Scons.

I'm using Scons 3.0.1 with Python 2.7 on Centos 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the manpage, you'll realize that "$(" and "$)" are inserted into command strings to tell SCons not to use whatever is between them when generating the command signature.  This signature is used to determine if it's changed since the last build and if so to rebuild.

So, with your example above, you'd have to track down which variable is introducing the $('s. Likely its _CPPINCFLAGS and reconstruct the CXXCOM without it.

Or you can create a callable class and set an Environment() variable to it and then do something like:

```
env['CXXCOMSTR'] = 'fizz\n${SANITIZE($CXXCOM)}\nbuzz'
```

Search for "Variable Substitution" in the manpage for an example:https://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-man.html

In your function you'll want to call env.subst(the_argument)
See: https://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-man.html#f-subst

Comment: If the user simply wants the full command string, wouldn't it work to leave the `*STR` variable empty? Not tested and from the top of my head...

Comment: That should work. But the original question wants to wrap that output with some other output.. (I also didn't have time to try out my answer to verify if it works or something similar.. perhaps today)

Comment: `env['SANITIZE'] = lambda s: env.subst(s)` to defer substitution is all the answer was missing.